# How to say how long an object will last?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, word-requests

I have a wallet that is made of a paper-like material, so I am unsure how long it will last. One other thing I am unsure about, is how to say that sentence in Japanese.

My first guess would be using 持つ.

> このお財布{さいふ}はどれくらい持{も}ちますか分{わ}からないです。

And if 持つ is the correct verb for the sentence, can it be used with other objects, for example a poorly made hammer that might break or fall apart?

Comment: `このお財布はどれくらい持ちますか分からないです。` <- 「このお財布はどれくらい**持つ**か分かりません(or分からないです)。」You'd (usually) use the plain form in embedded clauses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use [持つ](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/219381/meaning/m0u/) as well!

I usually see it used with food (has obvious expiration date):

> 牛乳って、美味しいけどあまり持たないよね。
>   Milk is good, but it doesn't last long.

But can be used with other stuff:

> あの服屋の服って、おしゃれだけどワンシーズンしか持たないよね。
>   That clothing store is nice, but their stuff only lasts a season.

Comment: （ちょっと変えすぎたかも・・。マズかったらrollbackしてください・・）

Comment: @chocolate いいですよw、あまり気にしないタイプですw

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 持つ would be used for hammers, but I couldn't find a usage sample on the Net because (I think) even a  poorly made hammer doesn't usually break so soon.

... 格安自転車は2ヶ月持つかもしれませんが2年持たないかも知れません。
.... そういう事がなければ2ヶ月では壊れないですよ。

> http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14141041859
>
> 「保つ」は、「その状態、レベルなどを、内部的に守っていく」意。望ましい状態にいうことが多い。
>
> 「持つ」にも、「長くそのままの状態を保(たも)ち続ける」という意味がありますので、どちらでもいいのですが、漢字の持つニュアンスでは「保つ」が近いとは思います。
>
> ただし、「保つ」は、「常用漢字表」の音訓欄では「ホ、たもつ」しか掲げられていませんので、常用漢字表に従って忠実に表記すれば、「持つ」になります。
> 「保つ」を「もつ」という読み方は、「表外音訓」と呼ばれます。(表外音訓：常用漢字表で認められていない音訓)

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be talking about food/drink, you can use [賞味期限]{しょう・み・き・げん}, meaning "expiration date" or "best before date".

For certain other expirable things (reward points, coupons, frequent-flier miles, etc.), you can say [有効期間]{ゆう・こう・き・かん} (or 期限) as "valid through" or "period of validity".